# ffmpeg installed but not the right version

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg

I am using ‪Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS‬ with Plesk version   12.5.30.

I have installed ffmpeg with these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

That seems to be the common answer when I search for how to install it.

When I do a version on it, I get this:

```
~$ /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

I am trying to install ClipBucket Installer v2.8.1 STABLE and it keeps giving me the message:

```
Unable to find ffmpeg
```

I believe this is due to it not being the right version. Here is the check in Clipbucket:

```
    case "ffmpeg":
    {
        $ffmpeg_path = exec("which ffmpeg");
        $ffmpeg_version = shell_output("$ffmpeg_path -version");

        $version = false;
        preg_match("/SVN-r([0-9]+)/i",$ffmpeg_version,$matches);
        if(@$matches[1])
            $version = 'r'.$matches[1];
        preg_match("/version ([0-9.]+)/i",$ffmpeg_version,$matches);
        if(@$matches[1])
            $version = $matches[1];

        if(!$version)
            $return['err'] = _("Unable to find ffmpeg");
        else
            $return['msg'] = sprintf(_("Found FFMPEG %s : %s"),$version,$$ffmpeg_path);
    }
    break;
```

Where do I find the latest version that ClipBucket supports?